# ChartJS Line Chart - Points Connected out of order for Timeseries in Angular 6

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-chart

I am working in Angular 6, using ChartJS for Angular.

I am trying to plot a timeseries of values using a line plot. This line plot plots x and y values, where x is time (passed it as unix timestamp) and y is some value. Unfortunately, when ChartJS plots this, my points end up plotted "out of order", or so I think.

Below I am including Chart options I used. Is there a setting that will let me have a pretty time series line? If I switch X to be integers, I get a plot that looks normal.

**In Component.ts file:**

```
  public chartData = [
    {data: [
      {x: 1539156000000, y: 0},
      {x: 1539156480000, y: 0},
      {x: 1539156300000, y: 0},
      {x: 1539156600000, y: 3051},
      {x: 1539155640000, y: 0}
    ], 
      label: 'A1', fill: false, borderColor: 'red'}
  ];

 public chartType = 'line';
 public chartLegend = true;

  public chartOptions = {
    elements: {
      line: {
          tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
      }
    },
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        distribution: 'series',
        time: {
          unit: 'minute'
        }
      }]
    }
  };
```

[image: Result of ChartJS Plot]

If curious, in component.html file, I have a piece of code that looks like so:

```
  <canvas baseChart
          [datasets]="chartData"
          [options]="chartOptions"
          [legend]="chartLegend"
          [chartType]="chartType">
  </canvas>
```

Desired look of chart (this is produced by changing X from time to integers, ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, but I want to be able to use the unix timestamp.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your time values using the new Date().
ChartJS assumes it is a Date.

Try if the below works :

```
 public chartData = [
{data: [
  {x: Date.parse(1539156000000), y: 0},
  {x: Date.parse(1539156480000), y: 0},
  {x: Date.parse(1539156300000), y: 0},
  {x: Date.parse(1539156600000), y: 3051},
  {x: Date.parse(1539155640000), y: 0}
], 
  label: 'A1', fill: false, borderColor: 'red'}
]
```

Comment: So, turns out my issue was that the time series was not actually sorted before I passed it in. However, your answer addresses how to potentially pass in other time formats, so thank you for the contribution.